# ussp-push from python not working

Tags: python, bash

I would like to write a python script that sends a file to my android phone.
I will run the script from my phone via ssh.
I tried the following codes but none of them was working. I did not get any errors, but when I try to test it I do not get anything on my phone via Bluetooth.

```
from subprocess import call

call(['ussp-push', '0C:D6:xx:xx:xx:xx@1x', '/home/pi/alfred.jpg', 'ana.jpg'])
```

## ***************************************************************

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 

process = Popen(['ussp-push', '0C:D6:xx:xx:xx:xx@1x', '/home/pi/alfred.jpg' 'ana.jpg'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Does anyone see what the problem could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result if you run `ussp-push 0C:D6:xx:xx:xx:xx@1x /home/pi/alfred.jpg ana.jpg` without Python, from command line?

Comment: it works without python, via putty/ssh

Comment: Check `process.returncode`. Or use `check_call` or `check_output`: output = `check_output(['ussp-push', '0C:D6:xx:xx:xx:xx@1x', '/home/pi/alfred.jpg' 'ana.jpg'], stderr=STDOUT)` to get an exception on any error in a subprocess.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = check_output(['ussp-push', '0C:D6:xx:xx:xx:xx@1x', '/home/pi/alfred.jpg' 'ana.jpg'], stderr=STDOUT)
```

`check_output` returns subprocess' stdout and also checks its exit code. So it raises an exception on any error in a subprocess.